# rails admin customization of selects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

In rails_admin, associations between models is represented by 2 select fields. You can move items from one field to another and save reference between objects. Those fields are filled by object's "name", and if "name" is empty it's filled by object's id. How can I change this logic to fill selects by some other object field.

e.g. I have 2 models. User and Post (many-to-many). User always has a non empty "email" field, and "name" field is sometimes empty. So then I check Post objects and a want to see related users. name of some user is empty so I see "id". Is it possible to replace "name" to "email" in this presentation?

Comment: Are you asking to rename the column, or to actually change the data stored in the column?

Comment: data stored in column. another example - if object have no field "name" and have field "user_name" we can define in model method name and it's use "user_name" for presentation in references. but i allready have field name and this trick doesn't work

Comment: You can actually create a model method `name`, even though you already have the field `name`. That method would just override the field, but you can still access the field using `read_attribute`

Comment: @FeifanZ i'am not sure that is best way, but i'll mark you answer as correct) thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer based on comments**

Something like this in the `Post` model:

```
def display_name
  user.name.blank? ? user.email : user.name
end
```

This creates a method that checks if the user's name is blank. If it is, show the user's email. Otherwise, show the user's name. When you're displaying your posts, you can call `post.display_name`.

---

Once you've created an `email` column on `Post`, you can loop over the `post`s and get the user's email:

```
Post.all.each do |p|
  u = p.user
  email = u.email
  p.email = email
  p.save
end
```

---

You can create an `email` column either by adding another column:

```
rails g migration add_email_to_posts email:string
```

Or by renaming an existing column (inside a migration file):

```
rename_column :posts, :name, :email
```

Comment: sorry, but where is no need in changing of db structure. i just need to change representation for rails admin.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what you mean. What columns does `Post` have, and can you give an example of a single `Post`, before and after the change?

Comment: do you see empty string? this is object but it's "name" is empty.